# Get LTE signal strength on Nexus 5

Tags: android, rssi, signal-strength, lte

I have an app which calculates RSSI from a data of SignalStrength object. On Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.2) in LTE network ASU level differs from the value in System Settings. So RSSI differs too.

Here is a screenshot with Toast message made by the app:

[image: screenshot]

I am getting ASU like this:

```
if (isLte) {
String[] parts = signalStrength.toString().split(" ");
int asu = Byte.parseByte(parts[8]);
}
```

Should I use PhoneStateListener's [`onCellInfoChanged(List<CellInfo> cellInfo)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCellInfoChanged%28java.util.List%3Candroid.telephony.CellInfo%3E%29) instead? (This way will definitely not work on Samsung devices.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer was easy: Settings displays RSRP, not RSSI. RSRP is stored in parts[9] of the array in the code above.